# Any function which calculates the number of months including the current month?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, date

Datediff calculates the no of months between two dates, Is there any function which lets you to calculate the same thing but also includes the current month.

Datediff +1 would give the answer, but just wanted to know if theres any inbuilt method.

Comment: Not sure about the c# tag. Is there a Datediff in c#?

Comment: @Jon Egerton, no there isn't, but you can add the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to your project and use Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff

Comment: `(new DateTime(2005, 5, 10) - new DateTime(2005, 1, 1)).Days / 30;` ?

Comment: Wait, you are looking for a workaround for adding 1?  Or are you a bit uncomfortable about tomorrow being a month away from today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built-in, because it is just that simple to include the current month by adding one, given that you know the diff won't include the current month. It's elegant enough for most developers' needs.